# Saving input from alert message-swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I have an issue that prevents me from display the input from the alert message into the table view. There are no errors but I don't know what's the real problem that makes the table empty.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var childTbl: UITableView!
    var names=[String] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.childTbl.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }
    @IBAction func Addchild(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alert=UIAlertController(title: "",
            message: "إضافة طفل جديد",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField) -> Void in
          textField.text=""

            })


        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "حفظ", style: .Default, handler: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



            if  let textField = alert.textFields!.first as?UITextField{

               self.names.append(textField.text)
                println(self.names)
            }
        })))
        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "إلغاء", style: .Default, handler: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        })))


        //to display the alert
        presentViewController(alert,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //UITabledatasource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return  self.names.count;
    }
    //function to creat a cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.childTbl.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.names[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your not calling childTbl reload in order for it to reload the data and display the new information added to the names directory

Comment: woow ,I forgot that ,thanks a lot

Comment: Not a problem your welcome

Comment: I just add more text fields in alert message ,I want to display first input of text field which is "name" in the cell of the table view  other inputs I want to save them , so the user can see them after selecting the name that refers to them